# Animating contents of WPF GridViewCell

Tags: wpf, xaml, animation, gridview

I have a WPF ListView, which View property is set to GridView. The GridView has two GridViewColumns, each having CellTemplate - the first column contains the button, the second one contains the border. My goal is to animate the border in the second column after clicking the button in the first column.

I have tried the following XAML:

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Items>
        <ListViewItem />                    
    </ListView.Items>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Height="25" 
                                Width="50">
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyBorder"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             From="1.0"
                                                             To="0.0"                                                                    Duration="0:0:5"
                                                             AutoReverse="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>                                    
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Second">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Black" 
                                Width="50"
                                Height="15"
                                Name="MyBorder"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

But when clicking the button in runtime, the InvalidOperationException is thrown with the following message: 'MyBorder' name cannot be found in the name scope of 'System.Windows.Controls.Button'.

What am I doing wrong and what is the way to do it correctly?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is unable to locate MyBorder element. In order to access MyBorder element from the Button event trigger, you should define it in the context of button.

Comment: You have to apply another approach. in order to achieve this kind of functionality

Comment: @Vikas you mean there's no way to animate specific cell in the GridViewRow using DataTemplates?

Comment: You can make use of attached properties for such purpose.

Comment: @MikhailKarpov you can achieve this as  pushpraj   provided the answer.

Comment: @Vikas see my comment to pushpraj's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using attached properties to achieve inter column animation**

using this approach you can also access the object or properties which are not accessible due to scope limitations

so start by defining a class to host the attached property

```
namespace CSharpWPF
{
    public class AnimationHelper : DependencyObject
    {
        public static double GetOpacity(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (double)obj.GetValue(OpacityProperty);
        }

        public static void SetOpacity(DependencyObject obj, double value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(OpacityProperty, value);
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Opacity.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty OpacityProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Opacity", typeof(double), typeof(AnimationHelper), new PropertyMetadata(1.0));

    }
}
```

xaml

```
<ListView xmlns:l="clr-namespace:CSharpWPF">
    <ListView.Items>
        <ListViewItem />
        <ListViewItem />
    </ListView.Items>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Height="25"
                            Width="50">
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"
                                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="(l:AnimationHelper.Opacity)"
                                                         From="1.0"
                                                         To="0.0"
                                                         Duration="0:0:5"
                                                         AutoReverse="True" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Second">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="Black"
                                Width="50"
                                Height="15"
                                Name="MyBorder" 
                                Opacity="{Binding (l:AnimationHelper.Opacity),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListViewItem}}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I have used the newly created attached property `Opacity` in `AnimationHelper` class to animate the value, and to set and get the value I have chosen `ListViewItem` as host element which is the common parent for both.

**Simple approach using resources**

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.Items>
        <ListViewItem />
    </ListView.Items>
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Border Background="Black"
                x:Key="MyBorder"
                Width="50"
                Height="15"
                Name="MyBorder" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="First">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Height="25"
                                Width="50">
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.Target="{StaticResource MyBorder}"
                                                             Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                             From="1.0"
                                                             To="0.0"
                                                             Duration="0:0:5"
                                                             AutoReverse="True" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Second" x:Name="grid">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource MyBorder}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I put the border in resources and specified in the template as content and used the same to animate,

result: appearance is same, with animation of opacity

Comment: Thanks for your answer, pushpraj. This code does really do its work in hiding the border. But the problem is that I could (and actually do) have multiple rows in GridView therefore, because of couple of reasons, the proposed approach won't work.

Comment: So you would like to hide the respective cell only, correct?

Comment: Thanks, pushpraj. I'm not quite familiar to AttachedProperties, so I found another solution of my problem. As I have a viewmodel behind this view, I bound the button's Command to my vm's Command. This command in turn affects the boolean property of my vm. Adding the DataTrigger to the border's style and binding it to the boolean property, I'm able to add the desired animation to the border based on property changing. In my project this solution fits well, but in general it seems a bit artificial.
So I mark your post as an answer because in general situations it's a very good solution.

Comment: indeed your solution is quite good. the view model solution works great when you have access to view model. however having such properties in model is not an ideal solution. attached properties helps when no such option are available eg. if you are binding to xml, data tables etc. do feel free to ask when ever you feel so. happy coding :)